# Storing additional data to image field, like title and alt

Tags: 7, media

I'm using [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget) on a node form and after the image upload is completed, I'ld like to be able to add a term ID (TID) of a certain vocabulary to each image and store this TID alongside the image in the same database table.

In my custom module, I've altered the related database table, adding the "tid" column. I've also managed to add a field to the form right after "title" and "alt" fields of each image using [`hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/7.x). My problem now is that I can't make the values to get stored or retrieved. What are the basic steps to add that "tid" field to my system?